# What is the name of the sound track played in Episode 296 of One Piece at 21:48?

Tags: one-piece, music

I searched everywhere to find this piece. I even tried the android app called Shazam.

It wasn't long enough to be recognized by Shazam. I'm talking about episode 296.

The track starts at 21:48 (when Franky shows up). [Here](http://www.viz.com/anime/streaming/one-piece-episode-294/5834/sub)'s a link to the episode.

It's the scene where Franky shoots Chopper.

Could you guys please help me out? This piece really inspires me.

Comment: The link doesn't work..

Comment: Have you checked Onepiecetracklist.com ?

Answer (score 1):

### Listen here: [OnePieceTrackList](http://onepiecetracklist.com/Music/182.mp3)

I believe the track to be "And Zoro is with Them..." track #12 of the album "The Cursed Holy Sword".